# How to trigger a custom method after registration (core method) in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I would like to send a SMS after each registration in Magento.

Can I write a method which should be triggered after user registration from core or should I write a entire registration on my local code pool?

Comment: Try sms notification https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html

Answer (score 5):

Customer controller fire **customer_register_success** event.

```
protected function _dispatchRegisterSuccess($customer)
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_register_success',
        array('account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer)
    );
}
```

You can use it to run your custom code.

Comment: Since the above method is in core code pool, if I write my custom code inside _dispatchRegisterSuccess wont it affect when upgrade magento?

Comment: You should never change core files. You can create simple extension to make an observer for this event. Check this article - http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/magento-event-observers-for-customer-registration-success/

Comment: Can you please refer this one? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69067/customer-register-success-not-trggered-after-successful-registration