# customer_register_success not triggered after successful registration

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I would like to send an sms on every successful registration. Below is my code. But I am not sure whether the method is triggered after successful registration.

app\etc\modules\Php_Sms.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Php_Sms>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Php_Sms>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Inside local code pool, I have created namespace as Php and module as Sms.

code\local\Php\Sms\etc\config.xml as below

```
    <config>
    <modules>
        <Php_Sms>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Php_Sms>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <customer_register_success>
                <observers>
                    <Php_Sms_customer_register_success>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Php_Sms_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customerRegisterSuccess</method>
                    </Php_Sms_customer_register_success>
                </observers>
            </customer_register_success>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

code\local\Php\Sms\Model\Observer.php as below

```
 <?php
class Ucs_GlobalSms_Model_Observer {
  public function customerRegisterSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
      $event = $observer->getEvent();
      $customer = $event->getCustomer();
      $email = $customer->getEmail();
          Mage::log('Successfully logged in', null, 'mylogfile.log');



      if($email) {
      }
  }
}
?>
```

Mage\customer\controllers\AccountController.php

```
/**
 * Dispatch Event
 *
 * @param Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer
 */
protected function _dispatchRegisterSuccess($customer)
{
    Mage::log('Successfully logged in'.$flag, null, 'syncProduct.log');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_register_success',
        array('account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer)
    );
}
```

But mylogfile.log is not at all creating. I guess customerRegisterSuccess is not triggered, should I do something to enable _dispatchRegisterSuccess method?

My questions are,

1. Will magento log work on Observer.php?
2. How to know whether my custom method triggered?
3. Why my sms is not sending? (No issues with SMS api. It works fine in core php file)

Comment: my you removed <models> defination from the config.xml

Comment: as per http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/magento-event-observers-for-customer-registration-success/ I removed that

Comment: no no you have to add defination of model since you are using the observer

Comment: okay, I will try with it now. Sorry

Comment: add model tag refer my answer

Comment: just check your xml files at the start of first line ie <?xml ?> their should be any space

Comment: Can i get solved code here or link of your code @anto.nishanth

Comment: @anto.nishanth  I also face same problem i need solution combine of above code and accepted answer .If u get free time plz overview my problem http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99275/how-can-i-send-sms-when-only-customer-register-success-magento-ver-1-9-2-2?noredirect=1#comment133705_99275

Comment: Use simple extension to check https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to change `<class>Php_Sms_Model_Observer</class>` to `<class>Php_Sms_Model</class>`

```
<global>
    <models>
        <custommodule>
            <class>Php_Sms_Model</class>
        </custommodule>
    </models>
</global>
```

Comment: <events>...</events> tag should be in global tag or frontend tag?

Comment: global is fine..

Comment: I added a Mage::log(...) inside _dispatchRegisterSuccess method in AccountController.php, but that log itself not created, should I do something to enable _dispatchRegisterSuccess method?

Comment: instead of log try to put echo 'somestring'; exit; just to check wthr the function is executing or not

Comment: Thank you so much, only log is not working, functionality working fine,

Comment: log is not working may be because you haven't enabled login in the backend.go to system > configuration > developers  their you need to enable the log

Answer (score 2):

update your `config.xml` with this one

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Php_Sms>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Php_Sms>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <custommodule>
                <class>Php_Sms_Model</class>  <!--issue here-->
            </custommodule>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <customer_register_success>
                <observers>
                    <Php_Sms_customer_register_success>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Php_Sms_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customerRegisterSuccess</method>
                    </Php_Sms_customer_register_success>
                </observers>
            </customer_register_success>
        </events>
        <routers>
            <Php_Sms><!--issue here-->
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Php_Sms</module>
                    <frontName>php_sms</frontName>
                </args>
            </Php_Sms>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Update `app\etc\modules\Php_Sms.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Php_Sms>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Php_Sms>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: modified the class attribute, but I added a code to write a log inside customerRegisterSuccess method. But after successful registration Log itself not created.

Comment: Please check the system.log error on my update question.

Comment: update both files from my answer @version_0.1

Comment: just now I noticed, if I put a log inside protected function _dispatchRegisterSuccess($customer) in Mage/Customer/contollers/AccountController.php, log is not printed. I guess customerRegisterSuccess is not triggered, should I do something to enable _dispatchRegisterSuccess method?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Will magento log work on Observer.php?

Yes

> 2. How to know whether my custom method triggered?

Just try it out:

```
require 'Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::dispatchEvent('whatever');
```

> 3. Why my sms is not sending? (No issues with SMS api. It works fine in core php file)

if the code doesn't run, the code doesn't run.

Are you sure you cleaned the cache, so your config is up to date and magento knows about your observer?

Comment: I added a code to write a log inside customerRegisterSuccess method. But after successful registration Log itself not created.

Comment: can you please look into my updated question

Answer (score 1):

How do you test this? The event won't be dispatched if you create new user account in admin area. Also check your system.log if there's no errors, especially with event dispatching.

What is that controller in your config.xml? If you use custom controller to perform user registration, make sure to let it dispatch this event (or some custom one) if you want to use it.

**Edit**: What is this controller used for?

```
    <routers>
        <userregistration>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>UCS_UserRegistration</module>
                <frontName>userregistration</frontName>
            </args>
        </userregistration>
    </routers>
```

Comment: Please check the system.log error on my update question.

Comment: There's some error in your xml config. Validate xml files you have edited, because it's not even misconfiguration, but a problem with the files' structure - it may cause your config not being loaded at all.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But unable to find any defects on xml, i referred app/etc/Php_Sms.xml and Php/sms/etc/config.xml, anything else>

Comment: Try to search your all xml files for `&lt;` and `&gt;`. I'm not sure if they're only logged this way or really some of your files got html_escaped (?). I ta may also encoding issue.

What editor are you using?

Comment: I found the root cause of the issue. inside Php\Sms\etc\config.xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> header should not be there, but after removing this also, method customerRegisterSuccess is not triggered

Comment: Check out my answers' edit.