# How can i send SMS when only customer register success Magento ver. 1.9.2.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I want to send SMS when  customer register success, I use customer_register_success magento event not working.
But when i use customer_address_save_after magento sms sending but problem here every time change address customer get sms alert.

How can i use customer_register_success event only for customer register success

\app\etc\modules\Sslw_Ismsregister.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>      
        <config>
            <modules>
                <Sslw_Ismsregister>
                    <codePool>local</codePool>
                    <active>true</active>
                </Sslw_Ismsregister>
            </modules>
        </config>
```

app\code\local\Sslw\Ismsregister\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <config>
            <modules>
                <Sslw_Ismsregister>
                    <version>0.0.1</version>
                </Sslw_Ismsregister>
            </modules>
            <global>
                <models>
                    <sslwismsregister>
                        <class>Ismsregister_Model</class>
                    </sslwismsregister>
                </models>
                <events>
                    <customer_register_success>
                        <observers>
                            <Sslw_Ismsregister_model_observer>
                                <type>singleton</type>
                                <class>Sslw_Ismsregister_Model_Observer</class>
                                <method>SendSmsRegister</method>
                            </Sslw_Ismsregister_model_observer>
                        </observers>
                    </customer_register_success> 
                </events>
            </global>
        </config>
```

app\code\local\Sslw\Ismsregister\Model\Observer.php

```
 class Sslw_Ismsregister_Model_Observer {
            public function SendSmsRegister(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {  
              Mage::log('customer_register_success '.'Mobile==',null,'SendSmsRegister001.log' );  //No log created 
              $msisdn = $observer->getCustomerAddress()->getTelephone();
               Mage::log('customer_register_success '.'Mobile=='.$msisdn,null,'SendSmsRegister00.log' );
//NOT Create Log here for this event

            //START SMS API Code here your code here    

          //ENd SMS API Code here your code   
            }

        }
```

customer_address_save_after magento sms sending (SMS API Working Properly) but problem here **every time change address customer get sms alert** Module Code below:
Just change customer_address_save_after==>customer_register_success
https://github.com/SSLWireless/MagentoSMS/tree/master/Magento_SendIsmsRegister/app

Magento Events Cheat Sheet (1.9) List:

https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/

Comment: `customer_register_success` event is fired when a customer registers on the website. It is possible to do so without having an address at all. So, event would be working, just you are not having the mobile number where you can send SMS.

Comment: Just after SendSmsRegister function  i put log that not work Mage::log('customer_register_success '.'Mobile==',null,'SendSmsRegister001.log' );  @Prateek if my function work then i can send sms

Comment: Try with putting the event in `<frontend>` scope from the global scope. Also, not relevant, but you have defined the `models` node incorrectly in your config.

Comment: i think it correct my another event work properly when i just change event customer_address_save_after function create log & working properly . @Prateek you may check that already using  live site https://github.com/SSLWireless/MagentoSMS/tree/master/Magento_SendIsmsRegister/app

Comment: Check this link : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69067/customer-register-success-not-triggered-after-successful-registration

Comment: @matinict you mean to say customers getting SMS on register as will as changing their address using above code?

Comment: @anto.nishanth Above code not working but github https://github.com/SSLWireless/MagentoSMS/tree/master/Magento_SendIsmsRegister/app  code as will as changing their address. Just change customer_address_save_after==>customer_register_success

Comment: This one can help https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html

Answer (score 2):

I got my solution describe flowing:

magento customer registration 2 way
 1. Create Account directly from sinup form
 2. Create account order checkout time

The Above module work only for customer_register_success observers events work when customer Create Account directly from sinup form.

> When customer create account order checkout time we need to  add
>   flowing

**Add following Line  Top of success.phtml**

```
    // Retrieve order
    //$_order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
    //$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
    //$_order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

    // Start Send Emai Here......
    $order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
    $incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId(); 
    $order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

   //Start New Customer Registration SMS Here           
    $customerAddressId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling();
    $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId);
    $msisdn = $address->getTelephone();                     
    $quoteId = $order->getQuoteId();
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
    $method = $quote->getCheckoutMethod(true);
    $customer_email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
    if ($method == 'register'){ 
    //code to handle if customer just registered to your site
    //START SMS API Code here your code

    //ENd SMS API Code here your code

     } elseif($method == 'guest') {
    //code to handle if customer is guest
     } else {                
    //code to handle for logged in customer
     }  
   //END New Customer Registration SMS Here
```