# Make a coupon valid for one month from the date of registering

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to make a **coupon time** bound if a **user registers** on the website I will send him a coupon `e.g. : CHJU20` that will be valid for only one month from the date of registering.

It should not apply after 1 month. Now if a new customer registers the same should happen with him too

Answer (score 0):

I have created coupon code programmatically.

First of all you need to create shopping cart price rule in `Magento Admin >> Promotions >> Shopping Cart Price Rules`

Make sure coupon code should be auto generated. So you must have to select `Use Auto Generation` as per below screen shot.

[image]

Then you can use below code.

```
<?php
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load(1); //1 = ID of coupon 
$generator = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon_massgenerator');
$parameters = array(
    'count' => 1,
    'format' => 'alphanumeric',
    'prefix' => 'A', // if you require
    'suffix' => 'B', // if you require
    'length' => 6,
    'from_date' => '18/11/2017',
    'to_date' => '12/12/2017', // if require end date
);

if( !empty($parameters['format']) ){
  switch( strtolower($parameters['format']) ){
    case 'alphanumeric':
    case 'alphanum':
      $generator->setFormat( Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHANUMERIC );
      break;
    case 'alphabetical':
    case 'alpha':
      $generator->setFormat( Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHABETICAL );
      break;
    case 'numeric':
    case 'num':
      $generator->setFormat( Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_NUMERIC );
      break;
  }
}
$generator->setLength(!empty($parameters['length']) ? (int) $parameters['length'] : 6);
$generator->setPrefix(!empty($parameters['prefix']) ? $parameters['prefix'] : '');
$generator->setSuffix(!empty($parameters['suffix']) ? $parameters['suffix'] : '');


$rule->setCouponCodeGenerator($generator);
$rule->setCouponType( Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_AUTO );

// Get as many coupons as you required
$count = !empty($parameters['count'])? (int) $parameters['count'] : 1;
$codes = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ){
  $coupon = $rule->acquireCoupon();
  $code = $coupon->getCode();
  $codes[] = $code;
}
```

Comment: In which file i have to write this code.

Comment: And this coupon code is valid for one month from the date of registering ?

Comment: You need to create Observer on customer registration success.
like : http://ka.lpe.sh/2014/08/21/magento-event-observer-customer-registration-success/
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69067/customer-register-success-not-triggered-after-successful-registration