# Send a POST after register sucessfull

Tags: magento-1.9, log, register

I need to send the customer informations through a POST to another endpoint after registering him/her.

I tried to create a module based in this SMS module ([customer_register_success not triggered after successful registration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69067/customer-register-success-not-triggered-after-successful-registration)), but (I'm not used to make modules) it doesn't generates any log file.

`app/etc/modules/Hypercube_Postregister.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
      <Hypercube_Postregister>
          <active>true</active>
          <codePool>local</codePool>
          <version>0.0.1</version>
      </Hypercube_Postregister>
  </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Hypercube/Postregister/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
  <modules>
      <Hypercube_Postregister>
          <version>0.0.1</version>
      </Hypercube_Postregister>
  </modules>
  <global>
      <events>
          <customer_register_success>
              <observers>
                  <Hypercube_Postregister_customer_register_success>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>Hypercube_Postregister_Model</class>
                      <method>customerRegisterSuccess</method>
                  </Hypercube_Postregister_customer_register_success>
              </observers>
          </customer_register_success>
      </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Hypercube/Postregister/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php
class Ucs_GlobalPostregister_Model_Observer {
  public function customerRegisterSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer = $event->getCustomer();
    $email = $customer->getEmail();
    Mage::log('Hello World!', null, 'mylogfile.log', true);
  }
}
?>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did my solution worked ?

Comment: No.. it doesn't create any log :/ can I check in another way?

Comment: Hello @Rafael, Please check my updated answer. I updated whole code.

Comment: Have you checked updated answer ?